# Right way to store parameters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Currently, I store the user_id in a session:

```
session[:user_id] = user.id
```

Later I retrieve the data when the user clicks on a specific external link and save it to the DB.

```
def offer_params
  params.permit(:offer_id).merge(user_id: session[:user_id])
end
```

Is this the right way to store parameters over multiple views? Is this save from changing by the user?

And: are there alternative ways to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This definitely works, but you can improve upon it. A user_id isn't something you want to directly give the user control over. Especially if your app is new and your user id's are sequential, it would be very easy for somebody to manipulate this number and look into other accounts.

One solution is to create a string field in the user record called "token". Add an index on this field, as well.

```
class AddTokenToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :token, :string
    add_index :users, :token
  end
end
```

When you create a new user, generate a long, random token for them.

```
require 'digest/md5'

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_create :generate_token

  # your other code here...

  private

  def generate_token
   self.token = Digest::MD5.hexdigest(username + rand.to_s)
  end
end
```

The token will be a 32 character string of random hex characters. The MD5 hashing algorithm is very fast for things like this, and hashing the username and a random value makes it almost impossible to guess someone's token.

Then you can store the token in your session instead of the user_id directly, and it's MUCH harder to guess random tokens. You can take this a step further by updating the tokens periodically. However, most authentication systems will handle session tokens in a secure way for you.